# SocketAsyncEventArgs and ReadAsync

Tags: c#, networking, sockets

When using the "SocketAsyncEventArgs" class and ReadAsync, where do i put the read buffer and where do i put the send buffer? or can i only read or send at one time not both? I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `Buffer` property of `SocketAsyncEventArgs`. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketasynceventargssampl.aspx) tutorial explains how to use the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` class properly.

The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx#) for the class contains some useful remarks and provides example code too (they're almost always a good start).

Answer (score 2):

You can only use a SocketAsyncEventArgs for a single operation at a time.

To both read and write async at the same time you'll need two SocketAsyncEventArgs objects.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/socketasynceventargs.aspx